# Preventing quick button smashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now, if I smash this "sell" button very quickly, so that the html doesn't have time to update, I can continuously sell same item and get credits each time, how do I prevent this?

Methods for user model:

```
has_many :drivers


def withdraw(amount)
    balance = self.credit

    if balance >= amount
        new_balance = balance - amount
        self.update credit: new_balance
    true
    else 
        false
    end     
end

def deposit(amount)
    balance = self.credit
    balance += amount
    self.update credit: balance 
end

def purchase(package)
    cost = package.cost
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      self.withdraw(cost)
      package.update user_id: self.id
    end
end

def sell(package)
  cost = package.cost
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    self.deposit(cost)
    package.update user_id: nil
  end
end
```

view with buy/sell button:

```
<% unless @driver.owned? %>
    <%= button_to "Buy", purchase_driver_path %>
<% else %>
    <%= button_to "Sell", sell_driver_path, method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

And my controller

```
class DriversController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @user = current_user
        @driver = Driver.find(params[:id])
    end

    def purchase
        @driver = Driver.find(params[:id])
        @user = current_user

        if @user.purchase(@driver)
            flash[:succes] = "Purchase succesful!"
        else
            flash[:error] = "Error"         
        end     
        render "show"
    end

    def sell
        @driver = Driver.find(params[:id])
        @user = current_user

        if @user.sell(@driver)
            flash[:succes] = "Sell succesful!"
        else
            flash[:error] = "Error"         
        end     
        render "show"

    end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle this on the model layer, so that you know no other code will ever be able to exploit this race condition.

Do two things:

1) Add a model validations for your important invalid-state logic, such as

```
class Driver
  validate :validate_not_previously_purchased, on: :purchase

  def validate_not_previously_purchased
    if user_id && user_id_change[0] != nil
      errors.add(:user_id, 'a user has already purchased this product')
    end
  end
end
```

2) Use the validation *in a locking transaction*

```
class User
  ...
  def purchase(package)
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction(lock: true) do
      package.user_id = self.id
      package.save(context: :purchase)
      self.withdraw(package.cost)
    end
  end
end
```

The transaction & validation makes it roll back if the validation fails, and the lock ensures that the package won't be "bought" by multiple users in a race condition with last-one-wins.

You also need to do some thinking around validating the business logic of user credits in the same manner, so that the purchase transaction will also fail if they don't have enough credit, etc.

This is a *great* opportunity for unit testing this super-critical part of your code.

Finally, a word of warning to keep the amount of logic done in the lock as small as possible. Locking is both a main feature of databases, and the bane of large applications' scaling problems. As long as you keep the stuff in the lock fast & light (which it currently is), it will be fine.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, but could just people explain what the line "!user_id_change[0] == nil" tests? And then, what is the difference between "package.update user_id: self.id" and then "      package.user_id = self.id
package.save(context: :purchase)"

Comment: !user_id_change[0] == nil should be user_id_change[0] != nil

Comment: It's saying "if the id changed from one id to another, this is invalid". user_id_change is a dynamically defined method that returns an array of [from-value, to-value]. See "active record dirty objects" docs (on my phone, or I'd link you to it)

Comment: when passing the lock: true to the transaction method, i receive an "Unknown key: lock" error

Comment: Maybe I'm remembering an older version of rails. I'll verify on rails 4 tonight, see "with_lock" in the pessimistic locking rails docs in the mean time

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way would be to insert a guard clause in your `sell` method (currently, it doesn't matter if the `package` currently belongs to the user).

```
def sell(package)
  return unless package.user == self
  ... # your original method here
end
```

This way, the method will do nothing unless the initial condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Zach's approach, you can also add some client-side javascript to disable the button immediately upon click. I had to do this in an app where a form uploaded a document, which made it slow to give the user feedback (i.e., remove the form page, etc.).

```
// CoffeeScript
$('.button-class').click (e) ->
  $(@).attr('diabled', 'disabled')
```

Or (this one happens to be JS ... sorry, grabbing code samples from two files :)) -

```
$('.form-button').submit(function(e) {
    $(this).find('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Both approaches have worked for me depending on whether I need the action in a submit or click handler.